# What is Colloidal biology and does it have any scientific background?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

There is the following bulletin published for the History of Chemistry Vol. 32: 105-118 in 2007:

[“MOLECULAR” VERSUS “COLLOIDAL”: CONTROVERSIES IN BIOLOGY AND BIOCHEMISTRY, 1900–1940*](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/~mainzv/HIST/awards/OPA%20Papers/2009-Deichmann.pdf)

written by PhD habilitation research professor [Ute Deichmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ute_Deichmann) at the Leo Baeck Institute ([LBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Baeck_Institute)) in London and leader of the History of the Biological and Chemical Sciences Research Group at the Instritute for Genetics, University of Cologne.

Therefore, the question is: What is Colloidal biology, what are the basic differences between molecular biology and does it have any background in modern scientific community?

Comment: The WP page on colloids http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid#In_biology has a useful jumping off point (see subheading "In biology"). There is a discussion in the book "A History of Molecular Biology" my Michel Morange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two antipodes: The molecular (or makromolecular) biology, which has the concept of large macromolecules which fulfill one task. This can for example be an enzyme which breaks down its subtrate. The properties and the structure of all molecules of the enzyme are the same and the factor determining the function of the enzyme.

The coloidal biology assumes that the function is granted by adding small amounts of an enzyme to water to form a colloid, which thenchanges the properties of the water in the way that it does break down the subtrate. Life was also explained as the sum of the functions of the colloids building the body.

This theory came up in a time when macromolecules and their functions where not very well understood. The better understanding of macromolecules rendered this theory irrelevant. This is also neatly sumarized in the conclusions section of the article you cite.